# Gimbal Beacon REST API - get all beacons including third party beacons

Tags: rest, api, ibeacon, beacon, gimbal

Is there a possibility to get all beacon (including third party beacons) of an organization?

I just found this GET call in the API:

https://docs.gimbal.com/rest.html#beacons_get_all

The expected JSON response:

```
[
    {
        "id": "beacon_id_one",
        "factory_id": "XXXX-ZZZZZ",
        "icon_url": "https://api.getfyx.com/assets/fallback/default_icon.png",
        "name": "John's Beacon one",
        "latitude": 32.7150,
        "longitude": 117.1625,
        "gimbal_latitude": 33.889916,
        "gimbal_longitude": -117.351344,
        "gimbal_location_last_updated_date": "2016-07-22T09:32:02.000Z",
        "visibility": "Private",
        "battery_level": "Battery Level of the Beacon",
        "battery_updated_date": "2016-05-28T15:54:11.000Z",
        "hardware": "Hardware type of the Beacon",
        "owner": "SELF",
        "beacon_attributes": {
            "key1": "value1",
            "key2": "value2"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "beacon_id_two",
        "factory_id": "XXXX-YYYYY",
        "icon_url": "https://api.getfyx.com/assets/fallback/default_icon.png",
         ...
```

This is how my request looks like. Response is an HTTP 200 and empty array.

[image]

Sadly it doesn’t returns third party beacons.

Comment: The link shown in the question returns "access denied", so it probably requires a login from Gimbal.  You may wish to paste an excerpt of the relevant content in a blockquote in your question.

Comment: oh sorry. corrected the url and response.

Comment: It's pretty clear that that service call is intended to return your registered beacons.  What makes you think might return 3rd party beacons?  To my understanding, that's not how the Gimbal server registration works -- it is all about keeping your beacons private.

Comment: there is the possibility to work with 3rd party beacons. So you can add them in gimbal and use them. So i think it should be in the response of this endpoint too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've revieved an answer from Gimbal Support:

> To answer your question, no, we do not return 3rd party beacons via our REST API and this feature is not planned for the future

So it is not possible to get third party beacons via the REST API.